# Return True or False if all the fields aren't empty in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a function that returns a bool value. It should return TRUE if all the fields in a row aren't empty and if there's one that is empty, it should return FALSE. The table has a lot of fields, so is there any way to do it efficiently in PHP and MySQL?

Thanks!

EDIT:

My current script is the following:

```
private function isFull(){
    $mysqli = //I create the connection
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1");
    if($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        if($row['field1'] != ''){
            $toReturn = TRUE;
        } else {
            $toReturn = FALSE;
        }
        //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: "Efficiently" compared to what? You already did it in an unefficient way?

Comment: Are you trying to validate required fields? (If so, this isn’t the way to do it; keep an array of required fields instead.)

Comment: Nope, I'm not trying to validate. It's a system that just allows the user to continue in the website if he has entered all the fields of the DB, but he can do it in diferent sessions (so maybe one time he fills two fields and the next time he fills two more).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over the row to check the the values, break and return false if you find an empty row ...

```
private function isFull(){
    $mysqli = //I create the connection
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1");
    if($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        //assume that all are not empty and set the return value to true
        $return = true;
        //loop over each field in the row ...
        foreach($row as $key => $value){
            if(empty($value)){
               //at the first empty field, set return to false and break the loop
               $return = false;
               break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        //no row?
        $return = false;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: I'd rid of `$return` and just `return`.

Comment: @RandomSeed - I am of the opinion that functions should have a single exit point. As a matter of practice, I only return at the end of the function and don't bury return statements throughout my code. This is a foundation of structured programming and makes debugging and maintenance much easier. That's my opinion ... Thank you for yours!

Comment: Agreed, this is a matter of taste I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep it simple:

```
private function isFull(){
    $mysqli = //I create the connection
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1");
    if($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        if(trim($row['field1']) == '' || trim($row['field2']) == ''){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If any of the fields is empty, it will return false. Else it will return true.

The `trim()` is used to remove possible end- and startspaces.

In case you want to not limit the results, just use a `while` loop. Once you return something inside your while loop, the while loop will break so the rest is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
$empty=true;
$qry = mysql_query($query,$connect_db);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    if($data["column"]=="")
    {
        $empty=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the same I wrote above, but the table has 15 fields, so I'd have to do that 15 times. Is there any more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Comparing 15 variables with `""` should take about 2 microseconds. Are you sure this is really where you want to put your optimisation efforts?